# Recieving data sent by ajax.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I would like to send data to a Node.js server running on localhost with ajax. To test this, I wanted to send the input of type text to the server and just log it there.
This is my Post-Function (which is called by clicking on a button):

```js
 function answer(){
                let data = {
                    name : $('#send').val()
                };
                console.log(data);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:3456/MyWebApp/Test',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    data: data.name,
                    success: console.log('post was successfull'),
                    error: function(textStatus, errorTrown){
                        console.log(textStatus + " " + errorTrown);
                    }
                });
            }
```

On my Server I try to collect the data with the following function:

```js
    app.post('/MyWebApp/Test', function(request,response){
        console.log(request.body.data);
    });
    
app.listen(3456);
```

My problem is, that the value on my server (in the above console.log) is always undefined.
I already tried to send the whole json-Object with dataType-Parameter  json instead of text, but then I get an error in my server for trying to read a property value of something undefined. How do I have to implement the app.post function, to make the data readable and work with it?

I hope it is possible to understand what I am trying to achieve and what my problem is, I dont really know much about Node.js or Ajax, still I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Change `data: data.name` to `data: data`

Comment: maybe you are not consuming your `request`  correctly. Try `console.log(request)` inside the `app.post` method and see what it outputs.

Comment: Look in your network tab, what are you sending?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-to-process-post-data-in-node-js

Comment: And it should be `console.log(req.body.name)`

Comment: @Michael I looked in my network tab and the body of what I send is always empty, body was also empty when I logged the whole request on Node.js site but I dont understand why it should be empty

Comment: Well at least you now know that the issue is with the request. I think you may need to send an object in data not a primitive.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending one string value **data.name** so your http request **Content-Type** would be **plain/text**
At **NodeJS** side you're using **express** library and it doesn't provide post request body by default.
You need to collect post request body using "data" event

```
request.on("data", callback);
```

Comment: If you want to parse **JSON** on express you need to use express json middleware
`app.use(express.json())`